# Pass Environment Variable to XCode Build

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal, environment

ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment will only be filled with values from XCode schemes. But what about operating system wide environment variables? I do have an environment variable USERNAME which I would like to use in my XCUITest. But I cannot pass it to my test. How can you pass it through?

After adding USERNAME to launchctl environment, my terminal will allow those commands:

```
launchctl getenv USERNAME
user123

echo $USERNAME
user123
```

I can then use this value in some custom build script within Xcode:

```
echo $USERNAME
```

It prints out "user123". I would like to know if there was any clean way of passing this value to my app / to my XCUI-Tests.

Comment: what are you using to create Xcode projects ? cmake can set env variables.

Comment: My environment variable is already set. But XCode won't read it.

Comment: You say "my environment variable is already set". But in what environment? Are you talking about something you set in your shell? It may be available in a shell script / Terminal, but a Mac app does not run in a shell script. There is a way to make custom environment variables available to an app, but that isn't the way.

Comment: It should be available to a Mac app if it's available for launchctl, right? (I added this info to the question)